# Handle multiple Checkboxed in a State:Array. How to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, jsx

I have a long list of checkboxes (not that optimised) and I want to get them in a state:Array(the checked one) and I'm not really sure how to handle it hope for help(should also handle uncheck when clicked)...

the question is how do I HandleCheckbox.

```js
this.state = {
  checkboxed: [],
}
```

```html
<div className=' row float-center d-flex justify-content-center '>
<label className='m-3'>
    <input name='1' type='checkbox' checked={this.state.isGoing} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    1
</label>
<label className=' m-3'>
    <input name='1.5' type='checkbox' checked={this.state.isGoing} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    1.5
</label>
<label className=' m-3'>
    <input name='2' type='checkbox' checked={this.state.isGoing} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    2
</label>
<label className=' m-3'>
    <input name='2.5' type='checkbox' checked={this.state.isGoing} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    2.5
</label>
<label className=' m-3'>
    <input name='3' type='checkbox' checked={this.state.isGoing} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    3
</label>
<label className=' m-3'>
    <input name='3.5' type='checkbox' checked={this.state.isGoing} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    3.5
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many checkboxes as you want by creating an array of objects.
Ideas are as follows:

1. Create an array of objects of checkboxes:

```js
const checkboxes = [
  {
    name: '1',
    key: '1',
    label: '1',
  },
  {
    name: '1.5',
    key: '1.5',
    label: '1.5',
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    key: '2',
    label: '2',
  },
  {
    name: '2.5',
    key: '2.5',
    label: '2.5',
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    key: '3',
    label: '3',
  },
  {
    name: '3.5',
    key: '3.5',
    label: '3.5',
  }
];
```

2. Create a Checkbox component like this.

```js
const Checkbox = ({ type = 'checkbox', name, checked = false, onChange }) => (
  <input type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
);
```

3. Declare a map as a state so that you can get or update a specific checkbox.

```js
this.state = {
    checkedItems: new Map(),
}
```

4. Update your state in the function when clicked on checkbox.

```js
handleChange(e) {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState(prevState => ({ checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked) }));
}
```

5. All together: **your `App.js` file should be like this**

```js
import React from 'react';

const Checkbox = ({ type = 'checkbox', name, checked = false, onChange }) => (
  <input type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
);

const checkboxes = [
  {
    name: '1',
    key: '1',
    label: '1',
  },
  {
    name: '1.5',
    key: '1.5',
    label: '1.5',
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    key: '2',
    label: '2',
  },
  {
    name: '2.5',
    key: '2.5',
    label: '2.5',
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    key: '3',
    label: '3',
  },
  {
    name: '3.5',
    key: '3.5',
    label: '3.5',
  }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: new Map(),
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    console.log(item);
    console.log(isChecked);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked) }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='row float-center d-flex justify-content-center'>
        {
          checkboxes.map(item => (
            <label key={item.key} className='m-3'>
              <Checkbox name={item.name} checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.name)} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              {item.name}
            </label>
          ))
        }
      </div >
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: I think thats your god by himself. if its possible to keep contact I will be happy

Comment: Sorry, which contact? Also, upvote can be really appreciating :)

Comment: like discord skype or something

Comment: This is my skype: `Pabon_CSE`, you can mail me as well. I use skype very rarely.

Comment: what is your mail?

Comment: i can an error that say : Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined but I defined it...

Comment: Are you using Class component or Functional Component? This is an example of class component. It should work. Working in my case. Just write the code exactly given in step 5.

Comment: did it my probleme after i get it how do i put all the values i a array to pass it in emailjs.

Comment: when i console.log(checkedItems i get)  Map(2) {"1" => true, "1.5" => true}

Comment: i want only the true value.

Comment: If you want a specific value you can do this: `checkedItems.get(item)`, here item is the name of the checkbox.

Comment: i want all the values that are tru in the checkedItems

Comment: mail me at `prerajulization01@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to set the state with the appropriate value in the this.handleInputChange function.

something like this:

```js
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const self = this;
    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
        const stateValues = self.state.checkboxed;
        stateValues.push(event.currentTarget.name;
        self.setState({ checkboxed: stateValues });
    }
}
```