# How to handle multiple Checkboxes in a React State: multiple Arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

guys I just used the Shahnawaz example here [Handle multiple Checkboxed in a State:Array. How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061977/handle-multiple-checkboxed-in-a-statearray-how-to)
but stuck with multiple true IDs when clicking on names/categories with the same projects, for example, will give you duplicated project1 and project2 when checked === true for two categories.....

checked1 (english === true) will give you project1 , project2
checked2 (maths=== true) will give you project1 , project3
checked4 again project1 , project2 duplicated

Any ideas on how to work this out?

```js
import React from "react";

const Checkbox = ({ type = "checkbox", name, checked = false, onChange }) => (
  <input type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
);

const checkboxes = [
  {
    id: "31",
    category: "englsh",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "9",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "32",
    category: "maths",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "33",
    category: "marketing",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "34",
    category: "physics",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "35",
    category: "media ",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
      },
      {
        id: "10",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "36",
    category: "science",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "9",
      },
      {
        id: "11",
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: new Map(),
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    console.log(item);
    console.log(isChecked);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row float-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        {checkboxes.map((item) => (
          <label key={item.key} className="m-3">
            <Checkbox
              name={item.name}
              checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.name)}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            {item.name}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want keys under `name` showing on the label, extract your key by doing this `Object.keys(item.name)[0]` rather than `item.name`. Also, pass an extra property(here `index`) so that you can print your desired values from the `checkboxes` array by the correct index. Here I've done that by using `event.target`.

**`Update:`**

If you want unique values, simply declare a state so that you can add items into that array(when checked) and remove items from that array(when unchecked). Finally, put your array in a set and you're done. Use `Array.from()` to convert the set into the array.

Here is the working code:

```js
import React from "react";

const Checkbox = ({
  type = "checkbox",
  name,
  index,
  checked = false,
  onChange,
}) => (
  <input
    type={type}
    name={name}
    data-index={index}
    checked={checked}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);

const checkboxes = [
  {
    name: { english: ["project1", "project2"] },
    key: "1",
    label: "1",
  },
  {
    name: { maths: ["project1", "project3"] },
    key: "2",
    label: "2",
  },
  {
    name: { physics: ["project4", "project5"] },
    key: "3",
    label: "3",
  },
  {
    name: { marketing: ["project1", "project2"] },
    key: "4",
    label: "4",
  },
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: new Map(),
      checkedArrays: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    let [key, value] = Object.entries(
      checkboxes[e.target.dataset.index].name
    )[0];
    console.log(isChecked);
    console.log(key);
    var len = value.length;

    if (isChecked) {
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        this.state.checkedArrays.push(value[i]);
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        const index = this.state.checkedArrays.indexOf(value[i]);
        if (index > -1) {
          this.state.checkedArrays.splice(index, 1); // 2nd parameter means remove one item only
        }
      }
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked),
    }));

    console.log("Duplicated array");
    console.log(this.state.checkedArrays);
    var uniqueArray = Array.from(new Set(this.state.checkedArrays));
    console.log("Unique array");
    console.log(uniqueArray);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row float-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        {checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
          <label key={item.key} className="m-3">
            <Checkbox
              name={Object.keys(item.name)[0]}
              index={index}
              checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(Object.keys(item.name)[0])}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            {Object.keys(item.name)[0]}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**`2nd update based on the requirements`**

```
import React from "react";

const Checkbox = ({
  type = "checkbox",
  name,
  index,
  checked = false,
  onChange,
}) => (
  <input
    type={type}
    name={name}
    data-index={index}
    checked={checked}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);

const checkboxes = [
  {
    id: "31",
    category: "englsh",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "9",
        title: "This is the title for id 9",
        description: "This is description for id 9",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "32",
    category: "maths",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
        title: "This is the title for id 2",
        description: "This is description for id 2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "33",
    category: "marketing",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
        title: "This is the title for id 2",
        description: "This is description for id 2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "34",
    category: "physics",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
        title: "This is the title for id 2",
        description: "This is description for id 2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "35",
    category: "media",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "2",
        title: "This is the title for id 2",
        description: "This is description for id 2",
      },
      {
        id: "10",
        title: "This is the title for id 10",
        description: "This is description for id 10",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "36",
    category: "science",
    projects: [
      {
        id: "9",
        title: "This is the title for id 9",
        description: "This is description for id 9",
      },
      {
        id: "11",
        title: "This is the title for id 11",
        description: "This is description for id 11",
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkedItems: new Map(),
      checkedArrays: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    let value = Object.values(checkboxes[e.target.dataset.index].projects);
    console.log(isChecked);
    console.log(item);
    var len = value.length;

    if (isChecked) {
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        this.state.checkedArrays.push(value[i]);
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let index = this.state.checkedArrays.findIndex(
          (x) => x.id === value[i].id
        );
        if (index > -1) {
          this.state.checkedArrays.splice(index, 1); // 2nd parameter means remove one item only
        }
      }
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked),
    }));

    console.log("Duplicated array");
    console.log(this.state.checkedArrays);

    var uniqueArray = this.state.checkedArrays.filter(function (elem) {
      return !this[elem.id] && (this[elem.id] = true);
    }, Object.create(null));

    console.log("Unique array");
    console.log(uniqueArray);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row float-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        {checkboxes.map((item, index) => (
          <label key={item.id} className="m-3">
            <Checkbox
              name={item.category}
              index={index}
              checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.category)}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            {item.category}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this was a perfect solution. thanks again for your time and support.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)